# how to fast judge two double set intersect or not?

Tags: algorithm

I want to fast judge two double set intersect or not.

## problem

The element in set can be all range. The element in set are not ordered. Each set have 100,000+ element.

If exist a double `a` from set `A`, a double `b` from set `B`, `a` and `b` is very close,for example `abs(a-b)<1e-6`, we say  set `A` and `B` intersect.

## My way

1. calculate the range(lower bound and upper bound) of `set_A` and `set_B`

   O(n), n is set's size
2. calculate range intersection `rang_intersect` of `range_A` and `range_B`

   O(1)
3. if `rang_intersect` empty two set not intersect.

   O(1)
4. if `range_intersect` not empty, find `sub_set_A` from `set_A` which in the `range_intersect`, find `sub_set_B` from `set_B` which in the `range_intersect`

   O(n)
5. sort `sub_set_A` and `sub_set_B`

   O(mlogm) m is `sub_set_A`'s size
6. tranvers `sub_set_A_sorted` and `sub_set_B_sorted` by two pointer. find if exist element close, if exist two set intersect, if not, two set not intersect.

   O(m)

My way can works, but I wonder if I can do faster.

## Appendix

Why I want this:

Actually I am face a problem to judge two point set `A` & `B` collision or not. Each point `p` in point set have a double coordinate `x,y,z`. If exist a point `a` from point set `A`, a point `b` from point set `B`, `a` and `b`'s coordinate very close, we say point set `A` and `B` collision.

In 3d case, we can define the order of point by first compare `x` then compare `y`, last compare `z`.

We can define the `close` that if all dimension's coordinate is close , the two point close.

This problem can convert to the problem above.

Comment: What's wrong with your way? I'd probably just do step 5 and 6, but it all seems fine.

Comment: how do you sort the points ?

Comment: Using my way it still the performance bottleneck. So I wonder if there exist any ways faster.

Comment: @grodzi If we can define a `<` operator, we can sorted the points set. We can first compare x, then compare y, then compare z.

Comment: Step #1: define `very close`

Comment: @wildplasser For example, in double case, we can define `abs(a-b)<1e-6`, in point case, we can define `distace(a,b)<1e-6`.

Comment: for more than one dimensional data you cannot have an order that preserves closeness like you defined. You probably want to use a kd-tree of points from the first set and do range queries based on points from the second set.

Comment: @Sopel Why? We can first compare x, then compare y, then compare z. We can first define the `close` in one dimension,  For more than one dimension, if two point is close at all dimension, we can said the point close.

Comment: @Sopel I will go to have a look at kd-tree now, thanks for clue.

Comment: @XuHui "We can first compare x, then compare y, then compare z." Yes, this works, you could update the question to include the information that you do it like that for 3d points.

Comment: My way actullay is mapping the node coordinate to double. Using k-d tree will operate faster than the my way? What's your idea? @Sopel

Comment: If the search is one dimensional, you dont need a kD-tree. Just sort both lists, and do a merge-kind operation. Or; sort one list and lookup all the elements of the other list.

Comment: @XuHui depends on data, language, implementation. Algorithmically you can't really do it faster.

Comment: I would have a try :) @Sopel

Comment: what is the time you get when A and B intersect and when they don't?

Comment: you mean time consume? It can be obtained by time complexity above.@grodzi

Comment: I mean the real time, like you have implemented in c++ or something. Complexity is a given. But practical implementation may "prove" to be better even though complexity seems worse. I particularily have an hashmap proposal where you map every node to 8 hashes, checking the two sets takes about 1.6/2.6s on my machine (in js). I don't know whether it's better or worse than what you have, hence me asking the time it takes on your side

Comment: @grodzi Yesterday after I fix some bugs in my program, I try to reduce the call times of collision detect, this part is no longer the performance bottleneck. The real times depends on the point set data. However, I am really interested in your hashmap proposal. Could you please explain how can I map every node to 8 hashes?

Answer (score 2):

Some idea by gridding the space:

Let's take the point `(1.2, 2.4, 3.6)` with minimial distance required `1`.

We may say that this point "touches" `8` *unit* cubes of `R^3`

```
[
  (1.0, 2.0, 3.5)
  (1.0, 2.0, 4.0)
  (1.0, 2.5, 3.5) // 1   < 1.2 < 1.5
  (1.0, 2.5, 4.0) // 2   < 2.4 < 2.5 
  (1.5, 2.0, 3.5) // 3.5 < 3.6 < 4 
  (1.5, 2.0, 4.0) 
  (1.5, 2.5, 3.5) 
  (1.5, 2.5, 4.0)
]
```

If two points are close to each other, their will be connected by some of their cube.

```
    y
    ^
    |
  3 +---+---+
    |   |   |
 2.5+-------+---+---+
    | a |   | c | b |
  2 +---+---+---+---+--->x
    1  1.5  2
```

In example above in 2D plan, `a` is `(1.2, 2.4)`.

Say `b` is `(2.5, 2.4)`. `b` will touch the square `(2,2)`, but `a` does not. 
So they are not connected (indeed the min distance possible is (`2.5-1.5===1`).

Say `c` is `(2.45, 2.4)`. `c` touches the square `(1.5, 2)`. So is `a`. We check.

The main idea is to associate to each point its `8` cubes.

We can associate a uniq hash to each cube: the top level coordinate. e.g `"{x}-{y}-{z}"`

To check if `A` intersects `B`:

- we build for each point of `A` its 8 hashes and store them in a hashmap: hash->point
- for each point of `B`, we build the hashes, and if one of those exist in the hashmap we check if the corresponding points are in relation

Now consider

```
    y
    ^
    |
  3 +---+---+
    | a2|   |
 2.5+-------+
    | a1|   |
  2 +---+---+
    1  1.5  2
```

`a2` and `a1` 's hashes will overlap on squares `(1,2)` and `(1,2.5)`. So the hashmap is actually hash->points.
This implies that worst case could be `O(n^2)` if *all* the points land into the same cubes. Hopefully in reality they won't?

Below a code with irrelevant data:
(put 10**4 to avoid freezing the ui)

```js
function roundEps (c, nth) {
  const eps = 10**-nth
  const r = (c % eps)
  const v = (r >= eps / 2) ? [c-r+eps/2, c-r+eps] :  [c-r, c-r+eps/2]
  return v.map(x => x.toFixed(nth + 1))
}

function buildHashes (p, nth) {
  return p.reduce((hashes, c) => {
    const out = []
    hashes.forEach(hash => {
      const [l, u] = roundEps(c, nth)
      out.push(`${hash},${l}`, `${hash},${u}`)
    })
    return out
  },[''])
}

function buildMap (A, nth) {
  const hashToPoints = new Map()
  A.forEach(p => {
    const hashes = buildHashes(p, nth)
    hashes.forEach(hash => {
      const v = hashToPoints.get(hash) || []
      v.push(p)
      hashToPoints.set(hash, v)
    })
  })
  return hashToPoints
}

function intersects (m, b, nth, R) {
  let processed = new Set()
  return buildHashes(b, nth).some(hash => {
    if (!m.has(hash)) return
    const pts = m.get(hash)
    if (processed.has(pts)) return
    processed.add(pts)
    return pts.some(p => R(p, b))
  })
}

function d (a, b) {
  return a.reduce((dist, x, i) => {
    return Math.max(dist, Math.abs(x-b[i]))
  }, 0)
}

function checkIntersection (A, B, nth=2) {
  const m = buildMap(A, nth)
  return B.some(b => intersects(m, b, nth, (a,b) => d(a, b) < 10**(-nth)))
}
// ephemeral testing :)
/*
function test () {
  const assert = require('assert')
  function testRound () {
    assert.deepEqual(roundEps(127.857, 2), ['127.855', '127.860'])
    assert.deepEqual(roundEps(127.853, 2), ['127.850', '127.855'])
    assert.deepEqual(roundEps(127.855, 2), ['127.855', '127.860'])
  }
  function testD () {
    assert.strictEqual(d([1,2,3],[5,1,2]), 4)
    assert.strictEqual(d([1,2,3],[0,1,2]), 1)
  }
  function testCheckIntersection () {
    {
      const A = [[1.213,2.178,1.254],[0.002,1.231,2.695]]
      const B = [[1.213,2.178,1.254],[0.002,1.231,2.695]]
      assert(checkIntersection(A, B))
    }
    {
      const A = [[1.213,2.178,1.254],[0.002,1.231,2.695]]
      const B = [[10,20,30]]
      assert(!checkIntersection(A, B))
    }
    {
      const A = [[0,0,0]]
      const B = [[0,0,0.06]]
      assert(!checkIntersection(A, B, 2))
    }
    {
      const A = [[0,0,0.013]]
      const B = [[0,0,0.006]]
      assert(checkIntersection(A, B, 2))
    }
  }
  testRound()
  testD()
  testCheckIntersection()
}*/
const A = []
const B = []
for (let i = 0; i < 10**4; ++i) {
  A.push([Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()])
  B.push([Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()])
}
console.time('start')
console.log('intersect? ', checkIntersection(A, B, 6))
console.timeEnd('start')
```

Comment: fantastic proposal!